# Why permission of "ASK QUESTION" went away again?

Tags: support, questions, post-ban

I'm facing interesting issue.
On StackOverflow, I have been actively get help + help others, but on SuperUser, I am almost banned permanently..
due to my incorrect first steps while joining SU, I've been banned from questions..  Since that, I was active sometimes (answered questions, commenting..)

Finally, 1 Week ago, I was allowed to ask questions.
Then I asked only 1 question - [keyboard layout (United Kingdom) is automatically added](https://superuser.com/q/1146973/249349) (BTW, that was UPVOTED also), but suddenly I've been again restricted. (I remember, while opening that question, there was caution something like "If you wont do correct ... smth.... you can be again banned from questions permanently".. or like this).

What mistake I did again?  Will I even be allowed to ask some problems as SU?

Comment: The question could benefit from a little polish, but nothing strikes me as ban-worthy.  Are you sure you're actually banned again?  The message sounds like it might just be a reminder.

Comment: "Will I even be allowed to ask some problems as SU?". This can only happen if you Improve the quality of your existing questions (even the questions that have been deleted) cause only having 4 questions over a course of 3 years isn't enough to be question banned

Comment: He has a bunch that's deleted

Comment: @fixer1234 yes, I am actually banned again... I am not native english speaker, so, I thought that nevertheless my grammar/quality problems with questions, I should not be banned, for the reason I am no so perfect in English. I think SO is for all people, someone can "edit" my question to improve grammer, but, the main question/problem is visible in my writings always, so, what I ask, maybe is not bad questions..
thanks all.

Comment: @T.Todua chances are while your new question is okay and well received you are being rate limited by the system due to your previous questions. You may well be able to ask again at some point soon, but we don't know for sure as the workings of the system is not revealed.

Answer (score 5):

Your questions on Super User currently are a net zero in votes with a wild variety in quality and formatting issues. This leans toward your account being blocked from asking new questions for now.

Compare that against your Stack Overflow profile where you have a lot of old questions that are also in poor quality, but because they are old now have a lot of upvotes, skews your privileges on that site.

You will be allowed to ask again so long as you continue to work on the quality and formatting.